# State of NanoVDB in Blender 3.1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, volumetrics

1. Is NanoVDB enabled by default? If not, how?
2. Does one have to convert/modify a "normal" OpenVDB file in any way to let Blender know to use the NanoVDB library instead of the OpenVDB library? If this is necessary, how?
3. Are there any limitations towards compatibility of GPUs?

If I understand the whole concept of NanoVDB wrong, please let me know.
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I might be wrong on this but I think all of Blender's implementation of nanoVDB is here as a rendering acceleration only : https://developer.blender.org/T81454

Comment: Does this mean that 1) it is already enabled 2) i can use "normal" vdb files and dont have to convert them in any way